# CodeIgniter 3 Database connects to own IP

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, networking, database-connection

I am trying to connect to an external database using the CodeIgniter 3 framework. When I enter the database details in Codeigniter's database settings I get the following message:

*Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '{username}'@'{HomeIP}' (using password: YES).*

While I have set in the database settings that it should connect to an external database, it does not. It then tries to connect to the ip adress of where I live

I have already tried the following things:

- Disable firewall
- Connect via hotspot (then it tries to connect to ip of service provider)

When I use my phone to go to the website it does succeed in connecting, it is then most likely in the settings of my Macbook Pro (Big Sur)

Does anyone have an idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable remote database access on the database source.
That's why you're getting that message.